# SerialPort BaseStream BeginRead never invokes callback

Tags: c#, serial-port, beginread

I have a SerialPort object I know is configured correctly because I can send data to the port and the DataReceived event is properly raised.  However, when I try the solution presented in [How to use SerialPort class more reliably](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40636921/how-to-use-serialport-class-more-reliably) which suggests using calls to BeginRead instead of the DataReceived event, my async callback is never invoked, and the call to BeginRead appears to "hang".

```
        byte[] buffer = new byte[4096];

        void KickoffRead()
        {
            _serialPort.BaseStream.BeginRead(buffer, 0, buffer.Length, delegate (IAsyncResult ar)
            {
                try
                {
                    var actualLength = _serialPort.BaseStream.EndRead(ar);
                    var received = new byte[actualLength];
                    Buffer.BlockCopy(buffer, 0, received, 0, actualLength);
                    DataReceived?.Invoke(received);
                }
                catch (IOException)
                {
                    // nothing yet
                }

                KickoffRead();
            }, null);
        }

        KickoffRead();
```

I've tried calling KickoffRead immediately after opening the port, from the DataReceived event, and from a separate thread - none of that makes any difference.  I've also tried changing the buffer size to 1 thinking it was waiting for a full buffer - no luck.  Further, when I attempt to stop the debugger it hangs and must be forcefully terminated.

I am doing my testing using virtual serial ports (Free Virtual Serial Ports software) but that works just fine when I used DataReceived instead of BeginRead, so I discounted that as the source of the problem.

Comment: Do not use Begin Read with a serial port.  Handshaking (hardware or software) is archaic.  The Begin Read would need a connection to work which is only achievable with Hardware Controls.

Comment: @jdweng I'm puzzled then as to why this is such a heavily promoted solution.

Comment: The code is really opening a stream which is connected to a virtual port in the driver.  So rather than reading the UART directly you are using a buffered stream.  You are not connecting to a remote device (or PC).    You could be connecting to a USB port with nothing plugged in.So what is the driver using to indicate when the connection really begins?Is it using Data?Maybe a voltage from the external device? Maybe a Ground Closure? It is up to the manufacturer and driver to determine when the start actually begins.IBM users manual for a PC and Microsoft Windows Definition says it is optional.